# To unpack a zip file from url request

Tags: python, xml, csv, url, zip

I want to get this XML file from a danish website with the URL https://www.foedevarestyrelsen.dk/_layouts/15/sdata/smileystatus.zip, but the data comes in a zip file. This is problematic because I want to get the data sheet directly into Python for a school project, and not to save it local and convert it into csv. So far I have tried following codes inspired from answers to previous questions about this subject....

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_zip(file_url):
    url = requests.get(file_url)
    zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(url.content))
    zip_names = zipfile.namelist()
    if len(zip_names) == 1:
        SmileyStatus = zip_names.pop()
        extracted_file = zipfile.open("SmileyStatus.xls")
        return extracted_file

xls = get_zip("https://www.foedevarestyrelsen.dk/_layouts/15/sdata/smileystatus.zip")

data = pd.read_excel(xls)
```

and I have also tried:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.foedevarestyrelsen.dk/_layouts/15/sdata/smileystatus.zip'
df = pd.read_csv(url, 
                 compression = "zip")
```

Comment: extracted_file = zipfile.open("SmileyStatus.xls")
are you sure it is not SmileyStatus.zip?

Comment: So from a cursory look, `ZipFile(BytesIO(url.content)` should be what you want. That all looks right. What goes wrong? What errors do you get? Do you get them if you manually download and unzip and just do `pd.read_excel('path/to/you/manually/unzipped/SmileyStatus.xls')` (Your second method definitely won't work because a zip file is not a csv, nor is an xls)

Comment: First of all, it is a xls file, so I gave you the wrong information. Sorry!
I get this error message when running my first code: CompDocError: Workbook: size exceeds expected 27286528 bytes; corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

Know its an old post, but I just had a similar need and found a good solution.

import pandas as pd

import io

import requests

url = 'https://whatever.website/some_file.zip'

r = requests.get(url)

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(r.content), compression="zip")

print(df.head())

print(f"{len(df)} rows")